# Active Record Collection Association to arry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So far i did this steps:

```
a = Department.find(2)

b = a.employees
```

Then i get:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Employee id: 4, username: "humo
 era", password_digest: "$2a$10$wTDZnPCPdqbxF0.rg4GSD.4ez7IMAEKVNM/BweNyb2rW...",..
```

Next i called:

```
b.is_kind_of?(Array)
=> false
```

so how you see i dont get an array! My question is how can i get all of the employees `usernames` in a array? Thanks

Comment: `Department.find(2).employees.pluck(:username)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 > a = Department.find(2)
 > b = a.employees.all     # .all will actually fetch the records
 > b.class
=> Array
```

`employees` is an association, which you can think of as an object that contains the necessary information and methods to fetch the **associated** objects from the database. It is not an array itself, but if you call `b.all` you'll fetch all the associated objects, and if you call `b.each` you can iterate through them.

Comment: And how can i have only the usernames of the employess in the array? Is there a short code?

Comment: @JohnSmith You can call `.pluck(:username)` on the collection, or `.map(&:username)` on the array to get just the usernames as an array. The difference between these is important, but it's beyond the scope of a comment.